# Camel script does not run

Tags: apache-camel

I have a very simple camel flow to test writing scripts. It looks like this:

```
from("file://C:test?fileName=in.xml").routeId("ContentbasedRouter")
.choice()       
   .when(toXML)
        .script().javaScript("request.body.substring(3, 6)")
```

But when I run this I get

```
org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate: js: request.body.substring(3, 6). Cause: <eval>:1 TypeError: GenericFile[C:\test\input.csv] has no such function "substring"
```

I mean substring is a valid javascript function so why doesn't it recognize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` consumer send exchanges with body of type `GenericFile`, not String. If you wants the filename, you can use the method `GenericFile.getFileName()` :

```
from("file://C:test?fileName=in.xml").routeId("ContentbasedRouter")
.choice()       
   .when(toXML)
        .script().javaScript("request.body.fileName.substring(3, 6)")
```

If you want the content of the file, you can convert it to a String :

```
from("file://C:test?fileName=in.xml").routeId("ContentbasedRouter")
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.choice()       
   .when(toXML)
        .script().javaScript("request.body.substring(3, 6)")
```

See [GenericFile](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/GenericFile.java)

Comment: Well, does that mean I need to convert the body to string before the script?

Comment: you can if you want the file content, or you can use the expression in my answer - `request.body.fileName`. It depends if you want to keep the `GenericFile` for the next processor

Comment: Worked with conversion to String.